# AWS Device Farm IE Timeout waiting for page

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, selenium, aws-device-farm

I couldn't find anyone in my situation.
One AWS farm I wrote my own selenium framework and I use it there as a grid, chrome, firefox work fine with the capabilities options, but when I set it to INTERNETEXPLORER, the test keep failing with this option.

```
self = <selenium.webdriver.remote.errorhandler.ErrorHandler object at 0x7fbb123fa790>
response = {'status': 500, 'value': '{\n\t"value" : \n\t{\n\t\t"error" : "timeout",\n\t\t"message" : "Timed out waiting for page to load.",\n\t\t"stacktrace" : ""\n\t}\n}\r\n'}
```

It doesn't really make sense to me why this happens, but apparently, it won't detect that the page loaded, in the video it did load.

Below is the code I've entered.

```
 devicefarm_client = boto3.client("devicefarm", region_name="us-west-2")
        testgrid_url_response = devicefarm_client.create_test_grid_url(
            projectArn="BLANK ON PURPOSE.",
            expiresInSeconds=1000,
        )
        desired_capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.INTERNETEXPLORER
        desired_capabilities['IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings'] = True
        desired_capabilities["platform"] = "windows"
        driver = Remote(testgrid_url_response["url"], desired_capabilities)
        driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try to schedule a run with the IntroduceInstabilityByIgnoringProtectedModeSettings capability. If you are still facing issues can you please create a issue in https://forums.aws.amazon.com .